# Recursively filter the WP children terms permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove the parents's slugs for the permalinks of the WooCommerce product catergory taxonomy (`product_cat`), as WP allows both structures (`/product_cat/parent/child-one` and `/product_cat/child_one`) to redirect to the `child-one` archive page, as long as the child slug is unique (correct me if I'm wrong).

I came up with the code below, working perfectly fine, but for two level children only.

```php
add_filter('term_link', 'term_link_filter', 1100, 3);
function term_link_filter( $url, $term, $taxonomy ) {
    if( 'product_cat' != $taxonomy) return $url;
    if( 0 === $term->parent) return $url;
    $_parent = get_term( $term->parent );
    $_slugs_ = array();
    array_push($_slugs_, $_parent->slug . '/');
    if( 0 != $_parent->parent) {
        array_push($_slugs_, get_term( $_parent->parent )->slug . '/');
    }
    return str_replace($_slugs_, '', $url);
}
```

This code does remove the parents slugs for two levels of terms, but I cannot seem to write the code to make it recursive so it can handle N levels of nesting. I imagine writing N iterations of the last if statement, but that is way too messy!

What would be the best option?

All my terms slugs are unique and children's slugs are prefixed by the parents' upon creation.

PS: this code does je job fine, replacing permalinks in the menus, the breadcrumbs & the sitemaps.
PPS: priorty set to high in order for the translations plugins to do their jobs before overwrting the url.